# Local XML file download through C# passed to AngularJS not working

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript

I have a method in the C# backend that retrieves the XML file

```
string filePath = "c:\\Users\\" + User.Identity.Name + "\\.SCADAPRO\\WEBHMI\\DASHBOARDS\\" + "Horizontal1.xml";

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("No trend exists at the path: {0}", filePath);
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            else if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                
                Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "trend";

                return response;

            }
            else
            { 
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
```

In the AngularJS directive class I call the method from the service

```
public openExportTrendDialog(): void {
            // Add download code here 
            var exportedXML = this.trendService.downloadActiveTrend();
            exportedXML.then(function (result) {

                console.log(result);
                // Create the file
                var file = new Blob([result.data], { type: 'text/xml' });
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                // need to get actual file name for here
                var fileName = "trend.xml";
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(a)
                a.href = fileURL;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();

            })

        };
```

The download works however the only content that appears in the file is " [object Object] "

The service is below. There will be a filename passed into this eventually but I want to get the download working correctly first

```
public downloadActiveTrend() {

            var urlPath = this.urlHelper.getPath(App.UrlHelper.Path.DownloadExportTrend);

            console.log(urlPath);

            var promise = this.$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlPath,
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'

            })

            promise.success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                console.log("Request failed with status: " + status)
            })

            return promise;
        }
```

Comment: Which stack are you using? WebForms? MVC? Razor Pages? Web API? You could. have used just `return File(filePath,"text/xml","trend.xml");`

Comment: `downloadActiveTrend` doesn't return the file either. The response is logged but never checked or returned

Comment: Using a net framework class library with angularjs frontend

Comment: This says nothing at all. ASP.NET WebForms? MVC? Razor Pages? All of those run on .NET Framework. Since MVC, the easy way to return a file is to write `return File(...)` in an action. On the browser, you have to actually return the response BLOB. Right now you're returning the result of `console.log`

Comment: In Javascript you can use [fetch and Response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob) in all browsers, there's no need for an external library. You'll have to check your library's docs to see how you can retrieve the file from `response`

Comment: It's in MVC , the service returns the result of the POST call to the function no?

Comment: if I just return the file, how do I structure the download in the directive?

Comment: I'm using typescript also for the angular front end

Comment: `structure the download in the directive` what does that mean? The code doesn't change the file's structure at all. It just returns its contents and sets some heades

Comment: `fetch` is a Javascript function, available in all modern browsers. No matter the method, you need to actually return the file contents in `downloadActiveTrend`.

Comment: is the contents of the file not returned when the POST is called?

Comment: I have changed the method in my service to return the data however the XML file is still showing to be [object Object]